find the position vector within a system of coplaner points
a,b,c,d are position vectors of four coplaner points A,B,C,D. Here $d = \lambda a + \mu b + \gamma c$ and $\lambda + \mu + \gamma = 1$. AB and CD intersects at E. how to show that the position vector of E is $\frac{\lambda a + \mu b}{\lambda + \mu}$?
can someone give me a hint on where to get started please?

Did you mean AB and CD?

oh, yea it`s CD, thanks for noticing
